# How do I merge two components in react

Tags: reactjs

In angular, I could apply two directives on one element.

```
<div dir-one dir-two></div>
```

What would be the equivalent in react?

Comment: There's no direct equivalent. It depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
var FirstComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>FirstComponent</div>;
    }
});

var SecondComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>SecondComponent</div>;
    }
});

var MainComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <FirstComponent />
            <SecondComponent />
        </div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/20562/)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use fragments, https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

```js
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the component to be rendered by another component something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
           <h1>I am your father</h1>
           <Child />
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is explained in this [Tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/react-101) of CodeCademy

Answer (score 0):

Try this in App.js:

```
    import Component1 from './components/Component1';
    import Component2 from './components/Component2';
    import Component3 from './components/Component3';
    export default function App() => <><Component1 /><Component2 /><Component3 /></>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wrote this function that might be helpful. The advantage of this function is that it will not join(show) undefined or null if the component for any reason has not been made yet when you pass it to the function.

```
/**
 * Joins html or react blocks/ components with a separator if they exist
 * @param arrayOfComponents - array of components or html blocks
 * @param joiner - can be string, other react component or a html tag block
 */
export const joinReactComponentsIfExistWithSeparator = (arrayOfComponents, joiner) => arrayOfComponents.filter(Boolean).map((item, index) =>
    <span>{index !== 0 && joiner}{item}</span>);
```

You can pass the components or HTML block as below in your react component:

```
const component1=<div>content 1</div>;
const component2=<div>content 2</div>;

<div>{joinReactComponentsIfExistWithSeparator([component1, component2], ' - ')}</div>
```